# Accessing external css property in javascript code

Tags: javascript, css

In my javascript code, i am trying to access a child's class which is present in external style sheet. Using

```
window.getComputedStyle("className", null).getPropertyValue("color")
```

throws an Unhandled error: `WRONG_ARGUMENTS_ERR`. Do anyone see any issue in this?
I want to access the class property, which is present in external stylesheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i think you'll need to feed `getComputedStyle()` a DOM-Element, not just the ClassName

maybe try:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("className")[0];

window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("color");
```

Comment: @Max...I am trying the way you suggested, I think window.getElementsByClassName is returing false, as the execution does not enter the if(window.getElementsByClassName). I am using it on Opera browser. Any guesses for the workaround